# How to hide a child component when changing React route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, state

I have a dropdown `BasketContents` component (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852818/react-fade-in-element/)), which fades in and out when a button is clicked. I also want it to close when a the route is changed by clicking a `Link` tag. I.e. if it's already open on the `Checkout` page, if I then click the `Home` page link I want it to automatically close without clicking the basket's close button.

My `Routes.js` is the root of the app:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/checkout" component={Checkout} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
}
```

`App.js` looks in part like this:

```
render() {
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(
        this.props.children,
        child => {
            return (
                React.cloneElement(child, {
                    basket: this.state.basket
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    );
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <HeaderSection basket={this.state.basket} />
            <div className="content">
                {childrenWithProps}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The `Basket.js` component contains the button:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { open: false }
    this.handleDropDown = this.handleDropDown.bind(this);
}
handleDropDown() {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })
}
render() {
    return(
        <div className="basket">
        <button className="basketBtn" onClick={this.handleDropDown}>Toggle</button>
        <BasketContents 
          contents={this.props.contents} 
          open={this.state.open} 
        />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I did try adding `onEnter` to my routes but understandably that doesn't do much since it doesn't have access to the `Basket`'s `open` state. I would ideally like to set the `open` state of `Basket.js` to `false` when changing route (i.e. when clicking on a `Link` component). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that doesn't rely on `context`. The first thing I did, following the React docs, was to [lift my basket state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from the `Basket` component to the `App` component. This made it easier to manipulate it from a central location.

Then, following a suggestion [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3554), I listened for changes to the `browserHistory` in the `componentWillMount` hook in `App`:

```
componentWillMount() {
    browserHistory.listen( () =>  {
        this.setState({ basketOpen: false });
    });
}
```

The result is that when the page changes the basket closes.

Comment: Listening to history is a way. Additionally, if someone is using redux(or may be flux as well), best way is to dispatch an action to hide it on listening history. This way, you won't have to deal with state and props of the `App component`(top level component) for hiding the `<Notifcations />`(<Basket>) separately. And just the status from the props would help.