# React Component fade in fade out transition by switching of state?

Tags: reactjs

I have a dumb question of React Components

a. I could do react component creation by using State to control:

```js
{
  is_active ? (
    <div>...</div>
  ) : null
}
```

b. I could also insert opacity transitions, reference:
[React fade in element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852818/react-fade-in-element)

c. But how do I combine (a) & (b) into 
   1. fade in while is_active = true
   2. fade out while is_active = false

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the classes used according to the `is_active` variable, then this could do :

```
<div className={is_active ? 'fade-in' : 'fade-out'}>...</div>
```

There's also a [`classNames` package on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) easing all the class attribute generation.

If you want the component to unmount after it fades out, this is a bit trickier but you can find help in, for example, [React Transition Groups](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html) or [React Motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion) (the most popular ways to do this, feel free to find or create one that best suits your needs)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
{
  is_active ? (
    <div className="fade-in">...</div>
  )
  :
  (
    <div className="fade-out">...</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Although correct, this will create more code since you have to duplicate the entire content of the <div>.

Comment: @Luciano Yes, I agree. I also prefer the code that is in accepted answer.